# Can a crowded mitochondrial membrane limit O2 uptake?

Tags: mitochondria

The mitochondrial inner membrane is crowded with proteins (electron transport chain complexes, ATPases, etc.). As the proteins are packed more and more densely in this membrane, the diffusion of any molecule through the membrane should decrease, since there are less "gaps" for it to go through. I have no idea if this effect is insignificant for the entry of O2 into the mitochondria.

So my question is: Can O2 entry into the mitochondria become limited due to the high density of proteins in the mitochondrial inner membrane?